# Internal Server Error with Geocortex Essentials Manager?

Tags: geocortex

I have installed Geocortex Essentials 4.1.0 and configured post-installations.
However, when I opened Geocortex Essentials Manager there occurred IIS 7.5 Detailed Error as follows:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error  And Error Code 0x80070021:
>   This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens
>   when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by
>   default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location
>   tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

I have attempted to fix with applicationHost.config file but confusing where to change.

Comment: Please contact your Geocortex support team https://support.geocortex.com/CustomerLogin?startURL=%2Fapex%2FGSCHome

Answer (score 1):

This error can happen if a configuration section is locked, either in the applicationHost.config or in some web.config file located anywhere above the Geocortex Essentials application within the web site structure.

Please open a case with Geocortex Support, or through your reseller, and we can help locate this setting and advise how best to resolve it.  Depending on the setting, we can either remove the lock above the Geocortex application or remove the configuration within the application.